# PHP - Not able to pull email from this Json Response

Tags: php, json

The var_dump shows the following, I want to loop through this and would like tos show all the emails

```
array(85) {
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "Contact"
    ["url"]=>
    string(56) "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/000002HQRBYAA5"
  }
  ["Id"]=>
  string(18) "0030002HQRBYAA5"
  ["IsDeleted"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["Email"]=>
  string(28) "t@stics.com"

}
array(85) {
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "Contact"
    ["url"]=>
    string(56) "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/0002HQRBTAA5"
  }
  ["Id"]=>
  string(18) "0000002HQRBTAA5"
  ["IsDeleted"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["Email"]=>
  string(35) "test@gmail.com"

}
```

What I tried in PHP is this

```
$accID="3234234";
$url1 = "$instance_url/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Contact/$accID";
$curl1 = curl_init($url1);

curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token"));
$json_response1 = curl_exec($curl1);


$status = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl1);


$objContact = json_decode($json_response1, TRUE);
//var_dump($objContact);

for($i=0; $i<count($objContact['attributes']); $i++) {
    echo "Contact email is " . $objContact['Email'][$i] . "<BR>";

}
```

Comment: `foreach($objContact as $data) { echo $data['Email']; }`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Warning: Illegal string offset 'Email' in

Comment: check if you have anything in the $objCOntact. maybe it null/invalid json

Comment: Then that's not the actual `var_dump`  of `$objContact`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of arrays which each have an `Email` key, so simply:

```
foreach($objContact as $data){
    echo $data['Email'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I tried it says Notice: Undefined index: Email in echo $data['Email'] . '<br>';

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Email' in echo $data['Email'] . '<br>'; on line 75
0

Comment: @user580950 You need to update your `var_dump` statement then. The above should work if what we're seeing above is the actual output from that statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `foreach` loop instead:

```
foreach($objContact as $contact)
{
    echo "Contact email is " . $contact['Email'] . "<br>";
}
```

or with `for` loop something like:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($objContact); $i++)
{
    echo "Contact email is " . $objContact[$i]['Email'] . "<BR>";
}
```

Comment: I tried the here is what  I get 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in contact.php on line 76
Contact email is 
and its blank

Comment: @user580950 Then the result of `var_dump` is incorrect, try again and post the latest result.